# Windows 10 screen on/off event trapping

Tags: windows

How can one trap the screen off and screen on events in Windows 10? Note that this is not the sleep power mode, but just the screen. I've been unable to find any events in the Event Log that are triggered when this happens. I need to trap them in such a way that each distinct event can trigger an action (.bat execution in this case).

While Windows creates events for other power events, such as sleep (source: Kernel-Power, Event ID: 42) and waking (source: Power-Troubleshooter, Event ID: 1), but I don't see any event logged when the screen state is changed.

Background: Ultimately, I'm looking to send power-off and power-on commands via IP to the Sony TV I'm using as a monitor. It doesn't have a "wake on signal" option like a typical monitor, and its "sleep on no signal" is hard-coded to 15 minutes. (Some Sony models have a "Pro Mode" that can be enabled, which has the monitor-like behavior, but this X85J model doesn't support it.)

While I appreciate the suggestions for other solutions, I specifically am looking for a way to trap the screen on/off event, as indicated in the title. I included the background in case others may be searching for something similar.

*Edited for clarity

Comment: What about using a screen saver? I assume you will find a screen saver that if activated executes other commands so this way you could execute the poer-off command to the TV.

Comment: sens over ip? hows about an remote power switch for this case?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion, but a screen saver isn't ideal since this computer is a laptop that's not always hooked up to an external display. When running stand-alone, the screen does indeed need to time out and turn off.

Comment: I also wanted to do this, but with a desktop PC.  It happens that I have a WiFi power switch and monitor device, ie a gadget that measures the power used by the PC, which is WiFi connected, by Meross.  The power usage increases when the monitors switch on.   
There is a python API to read the current power usage (from a cloud server).  In the UK this is known as a Heath Robinson solution...

Comment: There are some clues here - https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/turning-off-screen-on-windows-10.14504/.   Quote:  "Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core to detect a screen off event on Windows 10 - (MonitorOnChanged event, PowerManager.IsMonitorOn). "
I'm afraid I haven't got it working yet.   (Looks like WindowsAPICodePack is something to do with C#)